# c warning - passing argument 1 of ‘insert’ from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, pointers, struct, insert, compiler-warnings

I'm a newbie to C programming. I have to write some functions/procedures for homework, and then test them with a make test given by the professor.

I have a struct with two element: the first element is a pointer to a list and the second element is the type of order according to which the list is sorted. Here are the data struct:

```
/* order type
NOTORD = no order
TIME = ordered by increasing time
POSITION = ordered by increasing position */
typedef enum {NOTORD=0, TIME=1, POSITION=2} ord_t;

typedef struct elem {
  double position;
  double time;
  struct elem * next;
} elem_t;

typedef struct {
  elem_t * head;
  ord_t ord; 
} lista_t;
```

I have to insert an element (given by input) to the list, according to the type of order. Here is my code:

```
void inserisciInTesta(lista_t *l, elem_t *el) {
    el->next=l->head;
    l->head=el;
}

void inserisciTime(lista_t * l, elem_t* pelem) {
   if(l->head->time >= pelem->time)
       inserisciInTesta(l, pelem);
   else
       inserisciTime(l->head->next, pelem);
}

void inserisciPosition(lista_t * l, elem_t* pelem) {
    if((l->head)->position >= pelem->position)
        inserisciInTesta(l, pelem);
    else
        inserisciPosition(l->head->next, pelem);
}

int inserisci(lista_t * l , elem_t* pelem) {  
    if(l->ord==TIME) {
        inserisciTime(l, pelem);
        return 0;
}
    else if(l->ord==POSITION){
        inserisciPosition(l, pelem);
        return 0;
}
    else {
        inserisciInTesta(l, pelem);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Making the test, I get these warnings:

> raggi.c: In function ‘inserisciTime’:
>
> raggi.c:42:27: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘inserisciTime’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
>
> ```
>         inserisciTime(l->head->next, pelem);
>                       ^
> ```
>
> raggi.c:38:6: note: expected ‘lista_t * {aka struct  *}’ but argument is of type ‘struct elem *’
>
> void inserisciTime(lista_t * l, elem_t* pelem) {
>        ^
>
> raggi.c: In function ‘inserisciPosition’:
>
> raggi.c:49:31: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘inserisciPosition’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
>
> ```
>         inserisciPosition(l->head->next, pelem);
>                           ^
> ```
>
> raggi.c:45:6: note: expected ‘lista_t * {aka struct  *}’ but argument is of type ‘struct elem *’
>
> void inserisciPosition(lista_t * l, elem_t* pelem) {
>        ^

What is wrong with my code? Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: Isn't the warning quiet clear: "*`argument 1 ... incompatible pointer type`*"?

Comment: Also there a dozen of questions with nearly the same title, this very warning. This is a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the error is what Tom explains. I'd recommend that you change the functions and instead of using a recursive call (i.e. the function calls itself) you use a while loop to find where you need to insert the element.

Take into account that you need to modify two pointers when you insert a new element: the pointer to the next element, and the pointer from the previous one. Doing this with a recursive function may be more confusing.

Also, check for the special cases of inserting at the beginning of the list, at the end of the list, and if the list is empty.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler warnings pretty much say it all.  Consider the first one.  `insetisciTime` expects a `lista_t *` as its first argument.  The bad call is passing `l->head->next`.  What type is that?  Well, `l` is a `lista_t *`.  So `l->head` is an `elem_t *`.  So `l->head->next` is a `struct elem *`, which is equivalent to `elem_t *`.  That's a type mismatch:  The function expects a `lista_t *`, and you're passing an `elem_t *`.

One of the two has to change:  Either change the function to match what you're passing, or change what you're passing to match what the function expects.  The compiler warning is saving you here, since there's no way it could possibly work as is.

The other warning has the exact same problem.